# View is not fittng to screen width in Android

Tags: android

I am displaying a pdf. Is there any way or any method to scale the different sizes of pdf pages according to the screen size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use  android:layout_width ="wrap_content"
    android :layout_height="wrap_content" in layout